# Is it a good idea in TI:3 to play with fixed alliances?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-3rd-edition

Whenever we play TI:3, we play free-for-all. Of course, during play you can make agreements with fellow players whom you are still free to backstab later. I was thinking about playing with fixed teams, like 3 vs 3, just to try it out. The problem is that my buddies have never agreed to it.

So now I was wondering: has anyone else has ever done this? And did it work out or not?

Comment: There are games better suited for 3v3 scenarios, if you'd like recommendations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never tried it, and I think that making and breaking alliances is a big part of the game. The fact that there can be only one winner keeps everyone on their toes!

How would you resolve secret objectives? Will you still go for the victory point path or would you try galaxy domination?

Comment: There are indeed a few issues to be worked out. For victory, you could say control x% of the galaxy. Like the Supremacy or Domination objectives. For the rest, I think it's not a good idea to play with the other objectives. Because then you would have to manage your team too much as in "Ok, this turn you get Mecatol Rex and then next turn I will take it and...". If you let a team achieve an objective as a team then most of them are too easy "I control 10 planets outside my home system" or "I have 9 technology advances".

Comment: I would just like to add another reason why it's probably not a good idea.. Coordinating everything between the teams would be so benificial that it would become more of a 1v1 where all players on one team agree on every move each player takes.